# Generating Xcode project for iOS using GYP

Tags: ios, xcode, projects-and-solutions, gyp

I have been trying to generate an Xcode project for an iOS app using GYP. I am able to generate the `myapp.xcodeproj` project file but the settings are for macOS projects instead of the desired iOS project. I have set the following properties:

```
'SDKROOT' : 'iphoneos4.3',
'ARCHS[sdk=iphoneos*]' : 'armv7',
'VALID_ARCHS' : 'armv6 armv7',
'VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphoneos*]' : 'armv7',
'ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH' : 'NO',
'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' : '4.0',
'TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY' : '1/2',
```

Do I need to set something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following link should be useful:

http://groups.google.com/group/gyp-developer/browse_thread/thread/f683ae11a54301b1/8be8243080675559?lnk=gst&q=iphone#8be8243080675559